# Developing for an ipod touch 4g

Tags: iphone, ipod, ios

I am a software engineering student and i signed up for an embedded apple development class
I have Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.3 and i have an ipod touch 4g

I understand that the 4g runs ios sdk 4.1 and i am aware to use certain features i would need that sdk. In addition, i would need atleast Mac OS X Leopard 10.6.2 to use ios sdk 4.1
At this time i cannot upgrade the OS. 
Can i still download an older IOS sdk, and develop for the ipod touch 4g? 
what would be the latest sdk i could use? I just need something to get me through the class!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to create an Ad Hoc distribution build using the old 3.1.3 SDK for Leopard, and then install the app on a 4th gen iPod Touch using the latest iTunes plus your Ad Hoc provision profile.

Answer (score 0):

the latest sdk that runs with leopard would be 3.1.3. If you install that one (http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809a.dmg) you probably run into problems when installing the app on the phone because the old organizer does not work with newer devices. Since the 4g ipod may not be downgraded either, you're only (free, besides upgrading to snow leopard) option would be to compile the app, then ask a friend with snow leopard to install it on your ipod. Maybe your university will offer some macs to use for that, since not everyone has a mac?

Comment: How could i test the app if i cant install it on the ipod until i get to school?

Comment: yes, that SDK would work with an ipod touch 2g or 3g, if you downgrade it to 3.1.3 using the organizer. And testing basic features until is possible using the iPhone Simulator built into the iPhone SDK. Also, hotpaw2, using the university developer program, there is no such thing as a ad hoc provisioning profile.